# How to remove special characters in XML through ESQL

Tags: ibm-mq, ibm-integration-bus, extended-sql

I am having problem with special characters coming in input XML.
How can we remove the bad characters which can come anywhere in the XML field through ESQL code in broker toolkit.
In the below XML, description field is having bad character  â€” :

```
<notificationsRequest>
  <BillingCity>Troutdale</BillingCity>
  <BillingCountry>United States</BillingCountry>
  <BillingPostalCode>97060</BillingPostalCode>
  <BillingState>Oregon</BillingState>
  <BillingStreet>450 NW 257th Way, Suite 400</BillingStreet>
  <CreatedById>005w0000003QlXtAAK</CreatedById>
  <Type>Prospect</Type>
  <Tyco_Operating_Co__c>Tyco IS - Commercial</Tyco_Operating_Co__c>
  <Doing_Business_As_DBA__c>Columbia Gorge Outlets</Doing_Business_As_DBA__c>
  <Description>As of January 2016â€”the property title should read Austell    Columbia Gorge Equities, LLC-dba Columbia Gorge Outlets---so the title should be Austell Columbia Gorge Equities, LLC.</Description>
</notificationsRequest>
```

Comment: Having such characters suggests that you have some problem with character sets. First you should check that your incoming messages have the correct (matching the content) CCSID set.

Answer (score 0):

Your file seems to come with a wrong encoding or was corrupted while the conversion from one encoding to another. If you are a MS Windows user you can open it using Nodepad++ and try to convert its encodeing to UTF8 or any possible encoding to check the issue.